# How to Iterate through IEnumerable with Unknown Properties

Tags: c#, .net

I have an many different `IEnumerable<T>`'s that have numerous properties of various types. I would like to be able to iterate through each property under the IEnumerable.

Example Idea:

```
var data = someSource.First();
data.ForEach(o => DoStuff(o));
```

Unfortunately I cannot find a way to do this, currently I am having to know the name of the property to be able to access it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Further Clarification:**
I am using ADO.NET/Entity Framework with MySQL, I have a MySQL Database Table with the following format: http://pastebin.com/P51hURaj

It consists of 60 Labels and 60 Types for those Labels.

```
using (var connection = new hyperion_collectionsmaxEntities())
{
    var customs = connection.customs.First();

    //connection.customs is a DbSet<custom>
    //custom is defined as: http://pastebin.com/XW8pfzbD

    //Need to Iterate through Customs, Ex:
    //var custom1 = customs.label1; Through 60!?
}
```

I need to output all 60 customs into a ListBox via AddStatus(custom*);

Comment: What is it you want to do? What does `DoStuff`'s signature look like?

Comment: So you don't even know the property names that you plan on using? I imagine you can use reflection to iterate _every single property_ on _every single object_, but I don't know if that's a good thing or not.

Comment: I strongly suggest to reconsider why you need to iterate into a IEnumerable of unknown types with unknown properties.

Comment: Just to add to my first comment, some example code of what I was thinking: `someSource.SelectMany(obj => obj.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.GetValue(obj))).ToList().ForEach(o => DoStuff(o));` However, I don't think this is a good idea. Like the other two comments, I think you need to clarify what it is you're trying to accomplish and whether this is even necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, please see my updated question with exactly why and what I am doing.

Comment: If I do not have a method of iteration I would have to literally go through each and every one of the 60 properties manually .... :-\?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly question the intended use here, but to answer the question as it is specifically, you can use reflection to grab each property of each object:

```
var propertyValues = someSource.SelectMany(obj => obj.GetType()
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Select(p => p.GetValue(obj)));

foreach(var propertyValue in propertyValues)
    DoStuff(propertyValue);
```

Or to be more LINQ-ey like in your question:

```
someSource.SelectMany(obj => obj.GetType()
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Select(p => p.GetValue(obj)))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(o => DoStuff(o));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work, please see my updated information.

Comment: Can you say why that won't work? I don't see how this answer fails to answer the question as currently given.

Comment: I mis-typed my original question, I am selecting a single object inside the List<> and need to iterate through ITS properties.

Comment: or u can add your custom `Attribute` to the properties then you can get the target properties so easy. it i just suggestion, it may not help that depend on your needs.

Comment: @Smarter use Chris code filtering the properties by name: `foreach(var propertyValue in propertyValues.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("label"))`

Comment: Exactly what I did! =D Thanks.